# How to extract frames from video using avconv

Tags: image, ubuntu, command-line, frames, avconv

Using ***avconv*** I need to extract frame from video. But frames should be generated on per minute interval i.e. if duration of video is 10 minutes so 10 frames should be generated and so..
Thank You.